# Is there a priority between MIDI channel messages?

Tags: c++, c, mfc, midi

I'm making a Converter that converts MIDI Format1 to Format0 using MFC C++.

When the program is completed and compared with the original file, there is no difference in the melody, but there is a difference in the instrument. For example, I play the piano in the original, but I play the instrument like a trumpet in the converted file.

I've looked at the MIDI documentation, but couldn't find an answer to this. Are there any rules that determine the priority between channel messages?

Comment: The main point of the question seems to be the algorithm for the conversion/processing of MIDI files. Without details it is difficult to guess about your problem. I suggest to create a minimal example MIDI input file and show the input and output of your program in your question in readable form. There are programs to convert between binary MIDI files and an editable text format. See e.g. https://github.com/markc/midicomp or http://www.archduke.org/midi/ Maybe this can be used to compare the input and output. I guess the source code is fairly big, so creating a [mre] might be difficult.

Comment: I have succeeded in converting foramt1 to format0. However, the instruments are different in some areas. I think the order of getting the instrument number from the Cn part of the Channel Message is tangled. There is no problem with the other parts and the converted MIDI file works fine. What I want to know is the priority or rules of the MIDI Channle Message. Let's refer to the homepage you linked to. Thank you.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add information, don't use comments for this. I'm not an expert for MIDI files, so I don't know if your guess about priorities is correct. My idea is: If we can see what exactly is wrong in the output file, then we might be able to ask specific questions about how your conversion works. Does your input file contain multiple tracks that use the same channel? Maybe you can use a different program to convert the MIDI file and compare the result with the output of your program.

Comment: I suppose you need to place all non-note channel events before note ones. Something like Control Change -> Program Change -> ... -> Note On/Off. That's what I do in some places in [my .NET library](https://github.com/melanchall/drywetmidi).

Comment: That sounds like you have either missed some program change messages or confused the channels in the note messages.

Answer (score 1):

In a MIDI file, events that have the same time stamp happen at the same time (in theory). The specifiction does not explicitly say how to handle this.

In practice, there is no order that depends on the message type; such events should be played in the same order they are written in the track.

So when converting to a format 0 file, you should use a stable sorting algorithm.

Comment: If you have the same time stamp, you have to sort them in order of track number!! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If the channel messages are printed first, and if they are the same tick, they are sorted in the order of the track number, so the conversion is normal. Thank you all for the answers. I got the joy of solving minor problems.